# maintain transparent background of image?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to html and css. Our assignment for AIT is to code a website however I'm stuck behind a bump at the moment with this. Basically, I want the logo of the website, 'Daft Punk' located in the center of the website to maintain its transparent background:

[image: Image so far]

with the code:

```css
.logo1 {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translate(0, 5%);
  vertical-align: middle;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

However the issue that I encountered is that whenever I scroll out, the image tends to stay the same size (I want it to shrink according to the zoom) and eventually suddenly shift toward the left of the page. The size maintained is possibly due to 'position: absolute' however whenever I change it to something else, the background of the image is suddenly white:

[image: white background]

when I change position:# to anything else such as 'relative' etc. How do I make it so that when I zoom out, the content / logo in the center will also zoom out / shrink and stay at the center at the same time without losing its transparent background?

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. I edited your question and moved the CSS code to a code snippet. Please edit your question further to also include HTML and all other necessary code parts to reproduce the issue. Also I highly recomment to move the `z-index` to a negative value not to colide with possible content. Also add a transparent background color: `background-color: transparent;`

Comment: code:
    <div class="container">
      <div class="logo1">

        <img src="logo.png">

      </div>